# Is there a phrasal verb corpus somewhere online?

Tags: syntax, computational-linguistics, semantics, reference-request

I'm working on a project where I have syntactic frames in the form of something like "N.agent V PP.stimulus", where each PP consists of a P and a N.

I have a set list of verbs, and a list of PPs for each tagged semantic category, but I'm finding that I can't indiscriminately combine a verb with any PP. For example, if I have the V "marveled", I could say "John marveled *at* the canyon", but not "John marveled **about** the canyon"--but if I have V "worried", I could say "John worried **about** the canyon", but not "John worried *at* the canyon".

Does anyone know about any corpuses that lists legal (or illegal) V-P pairs?

Comment: This isn’t about phrasal verbs, it’s about valence frames. Take a look at VerbNet and EngVallex, the best valence lexica I’m aware of.